# filtering based on dates in Matlab

Tags: matlab, date, filter, datefilter

I have a part of the data in a cell array show below.I am looking to create a filter which will help me

- Get a list of unique codes (since they are around 200 of them)
- count the number of occurrences of each of the  codes (P0702 , P0882)

between any start date and any end date which a user would choose

```
    '1F'    '2013'  'd' '6/21/2013' ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''
    '1'     '2013'  'F' '9/17/2013' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''
    '1FA'   '2014'  'F' '7/26/2014' ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''
    '1F'    '2014'  'r' '12/13/2014'    ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702'
    '1F'    '2013'  'F' '11/3/2014' ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''
    '1FA'   '2014'  'y' '6/27/2014' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''
    '1FA'   '2013'  'j' '11/10/2014'    ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''
    '1FA'   '2013'  'y' '6/13/2014' ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''
    '1FAD'  '2013'  'j' '1/23/2014' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0883' 'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''
    '1FA'   '2013'  'k' '4/24/2015' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''
    '1FAD'  '2014'  'm' '12/5/2014' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''
    '1FA'   '2013'  'g' '6/29/2013' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''
    '1FA'   '2013'  'u' '5/12/2015' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' 'P0882' ''  ''  ''  ''
    '1FA'   '2013'  'u' '5/12/2015' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''
    '1FA'   '2013'  'b' '5/15/2015' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''
    '1FA'   '2013'  'y' '7/13/2014' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''
    '1F'    '2013'  'j' '7/16/2014' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''
    '1F'    '2013'  'n' '7/23/2013' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''
    '1F'    '2013'  'm' '10/19/2013'    ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0882' 'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''
```

For example the output would be something like

From date :  06/21/2013
end date  :  12/31/2013

```
         Count
P0702    20
P0882    15
```

20 and 15 here are just examples (not true values) of the output.
Any help would be appreciated in this case.Thanks

Comment: @rayryeng- yes . i just gave an example of the output

Comment: Are you looking for a vectorized implementation, or could a `for` loop work?  Easiest case with your data and with cell arrays is using a loop.

Comment: @rayryeng- for loop would do.

Comment: Can you clarify what the first and third column are of your cell array?  Are those strings or are they vectors/matrices?  I'm trying to recreate your cell array but it's proving very difficult.

Comment: @rayryeng- yes they are strings .My apologies on that

Comment: Beautiful thanks.  I think I can get this done without a loop.  Give me a while.

Comment: @rayryeng, I just added a few `'` in front of column 1 and 3 to be able to rebuild his cell array.

Comment: @Hoki - Thanks!  I'm going to try to do this without a loop as I see you have a solution :)

Comment: @Hoki - In the solution below, Since the above data keeps changing ,creating a subset would be a bit tough.And also since the codes (P0702, P0882) i have here are just of two types ,but actually there are around 200 of these codes .This is just a small part of the data.Thanks Though

Comment: well ... then you have 3 questions into one: (1) find a list of unique codes. (2) find subarray between matching dates. (3) count occurrences of each unique code in subarray ... That is not really how your question is formulated. Please edit your question to include these informations.

Comment: @Hoki Sure will do.My apologies .Thanks for the inputs

Comment: @calib_san, I edited my answer, you now have your 3 functionalities.

Comment: @Hoki -Thanks a lot for the inputs and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will:

- find all the unique codes in your table
- find the lines which are between `dateStart` and `dateStop`
- count the occurrences of each code.

---

```
%% // INPUTS
dstart = '06/21/2013' ; %// starting date
dstop  = '12/31/2013' ; %// end date
%// code2count = {'P0702','P0882'} ; %// done below by looking up the table

%% // find unique codes
idxCode = ~cellfun(@isempty , C ) ;
idxCode(:,1:5) = false ; %// will not consider 5 first columns
code2count = unique(C(idxCode)) ;

%% // Extract dates
dateFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY' ;
dateStart = datenum(dstart, dateFormat) ;
dateStop  = datenum(dstop , dateFormat) ;
dateCol = cellfun(@(d) datenum(d,dateFormat) , C(:,4) ) ;

%// this contains the indices of the matching dates
idxDateOk = (dateCol >= dateStart) & (dateCol <= dateStop ) ; 

%% // now count
nCodes = numel(code2count) ;
counts = zeros(nCodes,1) ;
fprintf('%-10s   Counts\n','Code')
for k=1:nCodes
    counts(k) = sum(sum( strcmp( code2count(k) , C(idxDateOk,:) ) ) ) ;
    fprintf( '%-10s   %d\n',code2count{k},counts(k) ) ;          %// display results
end
```

This outputs:

```
Code         Counts
P0702        3
P0882        0
P0883        0
```